# AMP HTML amp-ads - Blocked Frame, Protocols, domains, and ports must match

Tags: nginx, adsense, amp-html, amp-ad

I'm attempting to resolve an error that is preventing me from showing google-adsense ads on an amp-html site that I built and am hosting on an nginx server. I have searched and read through quite a few similar questions on Stack Overflow, [Google Adsense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7183212?hl=en&ref_topic=1307438) and [Amp By Example](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-ad/) documentations.

I placed an amp-ad, per [Google's instructions](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7183212?hl=en&ref_topic=1307438). The page itself loads properly, but with for whitespace where the ad should be. In the console, I get this error (twice):

`Blocked a frame with origin "https://d-1234567890.ampproject.net" from accessing a frame with origin "https://example.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

I recently moved the Nameservers to a new server, which now supports `https` instead of `http`. The site appears to still be verified in Adsense, but is it trying to send the ads via the wrong protocol?

1. Protocols must match -- *seems* to be the case, as both sites are https.
2. Domains and ports must match -- ok, but how to verify these?

Beyond this, I'm not quite sure how to troubleshoot the issue, other than blindly turning off security measures. Should I be looking at my headers (`X-Frame-Options`, `X-Content-Type-Options`, etc.)? Or my `Content-Security-Policy` header? Or is Google Adsense still using the old http protocol?

FWIW, I am also getting these (related) warnings in the console:

`[Warning] The resource https://3p.ampproject.net/234567890/f.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it wasn't preloaded for nothing.
[Warning] The resource https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it wasn't preloaded for nothing.`

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you have an `x-frame-options` header then you are most likely blocking it.

Comment: I considered that -- but if I understand correctly, X-frame-options applies to iframes, not javascript, so X-frame-options should be irrelevant no? I can successfully embed soundcloud links, which use iFrame (and I believe those are allowed or denied in Content-Security-Policy). Also, if I understand correctly, plenty of larger sites use X-frame-options DENY along with ads (presumably Google). For the record, I was able to get a non-AMP adsense script to load.

Comment: @ShawnC. do you have some documentation or experience that backs up your claim? I have tested all available settings for X-Frame-Options, including removing the header completely, and the error did not change. If you are speaking from experience, please share some links.

Comment: I am also getting the same error at the moment, did u solve it?